Client is not able to establish a connection with FTP (VSFTPD) server
my guess is, this is because of TLS. It was working with centos, now moved to RHEL. Please help. thank in advance
Please find below log and vsftpd confi
Log
vsftpd.conf
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
userlist_deny=NO
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/datarecords/$USER
pam_service_name=vsftpd
ssl_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH:AES256-SHA:!aNULL
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
seccomp_sandbox=NO
listen=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_address=[deleted]
pasv_max_port=29001
pasv_min_port=29000
syslog_enable=NO
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
log_ftp_protocol=YES
debug_ssl=YES
